# Java RSS Feed Reader Android Studio

Tags: android, rss, feed

I can't find  a guide for the RSS Feed reader for Java Android Studio.

```
Have you some advices?
```

Thanks

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: This http://www.html.it/pag/19519/android-e-le-applicazioni-di-rete/

Comment: But anything shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to put it in a webview.

How I do it is:

```
package (INSERT STUFF HERE);

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class (INSERT ACTIVITY) extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.(YOUR ACTIVITY));
        //identifies the webview
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.(WEBVIEW ID));
        //loads the url
        webView.loadUrl("INSERT RSS FEED");
        //cancels all hyperlinks
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am working on a way to put it into a cardview, since the webview method doesn't really look good... I will post the code here if I can get it to work :)